# How to "bypass" encapsulation?

Tags: c++, encapsulation

The usual example with a unit.

```
class Unit {
    private:
        int health;
    public:
        Unit(int health);
        virtual ~Unit();
    protected:
        virtual void setHealth(int newHealth);
}
```

next, make heir

```
class Healer : public Unit {
    public:
        Healer(int health);
        virtual void healing(Unit* other);
};
```

In the implementation of *healing*

```
void Healer::healing(Unit* other) {
    other->setHealth(100);
}
```

encapsulation does not allow doing so other-> setHealth (100);

> 'setHealth' is a protected member of 'Unit' other->setHealth(newHealth);
>
> can only access this member on an object of type 'Healer' virtual void
>   setHealth(int newHealth);

In this case, you can call this method for "this".

P.S.: public method *setHealth* - do not offer. method *healing* for class Unit - do not offer.

Comment: You can add "friend class Healer;" to Unit. But that's ugly

Comment: I think that using a friend class would definitely not be ugly

Comment: I may be completely out of my shoes but why not having a specific  pure virtual function in Unit, having only Healer implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @EekTheCat, you could use a friend.

Alternatively, you could add a function to receive health.  You currently have a public function for setting health.  You can just as easily add a public function for receiving health:

```C++
class Unit {
    private:
        int health;
    public:
        Unit(int health);
        virtual ~Unit();
    protected:
        virtual void setHealth(int newHealth);
        void acceptHealth();
}

void Unit::acceptHealth() {
    health += 100;
}
```

You could create a new child class called the patient and implement the accept health as a virtual function of Unit, implemented by the patient class.

Your code is not complicated (thank you for keeping it minimal), but you could add tokens and security to pass around to ensure that health points are properly conserved according to rules that could be enforced in your virtual reality.

Comment: not every unit can heal. that's why I wrote in the P.S., that do not offer.
unit-abstract class. 
heir - soldier, rogue, vapire, healer... etc
healing - method for heir healer only.